# ControlID Help for a GrindView DynamicField DataField

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview with the following datafields

```
</asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="FullName" HeaderText=" Full Name" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="Gender" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="Race" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="DOB" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="Age" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="FoundFullName" HeaderText="Found Name" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="FoundGender" HeaderText="F_Gender" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="FoundRace" HeaderText="F_Race" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="FoundDOB" HeaderText="F_DOB" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="Age" HeaderText="F_Age" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="C_Similarity" HeaderText="Similarity" HtmlEncode="false" DataFormatString="{0:P2}" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="SubjectId" HeaderText="SubjectID #" Visible="false" />
    <asp:DynamicField DataField="JacketNumber" HeaderText="JacketNumber #" Visible="false" />
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Get">
<ItemTemplate>
```

I need to remove duplicate names from

```
<asp:DynamicField DataField="FullName" HeaderText=" Full Name" />
```

using this code which I found here.

```
string oldValue = string.Empty;
string newValue = string.Empty;
int j = 1;

for (int count = 0; count < GridViewSubjectList.Rows.Count; count++)
{
    oldValue = GridViewSubjectList.Rows[count].Cells[j].Text;
    if (oldValue == newValue)
    {
        GridViewSubjectList.Rows[count].Cells[j].Text = string.Empty;
    }
    newValue = oldValue;
}
```

This code removes all of my names in the Full Name column.  While debugging I see that all of the .Text values from the cells are an empty string.  So more research indicated that since the cells are in a template I needed to modify the code to and use .FindControl("controlID") to get the value of the datafield.  So I tried to modify the code but am having a problem figuring out the controlID for the FullName datafield.

All of the examples I find are using a label in the gridview and using the label ID as the control ID which will not work for me.

So my question is what is the control ID for a DynamicField:datafield in a gridview using EntityFramework and ItemType="theTableName" for databinding?

Thanks

Comment: After more research I found that I can add a DynamicControl to an EditItemTemplate so I have added these to allow both read and edit, and gave them an IDName so I assume I could then use that ID name in the FindControl(FullName).  But still cannot figure out the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my fields were set as Dynamic and since I am calling the code in the protected void GridViewSubjectList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) method there were no bound fields.  I changed the asp.net field type to bound and now the original code where I read the text of the cell is retuning data and I no longer need to use the FindContro().

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand, you are trying to remove duplicate entries from your data based on firstname. Why cant you do this filtering on the DataSet before you bind it to the Grid?

Comment: Great question in my case I need the duplicate names, but want to clean up the view for the user.